# iPhone / iPad IOS App Instrument Memory Count vs. task_info Memory Count

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-leaks

I have been using the Instruments Leak Tester and it gives a number for Total Allocations for an app around 1-3 meg.

But, when using the task_info it is reporting much larger memory amounts like 10-20 meg.

I guess I just want to confirm that the task_info is returning some sort of total memory including stack / etc where the leak tester is just reporting Malloc / Alloc memory.

Also, why would the task_info number be increasing quite a bit during the app when the leak tester is not increasing that much....

```
    struct task_basic_info info;
    mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(info);
    kern_return_t kerr = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)&info, &size);
    if( kerr == KERN_SUCCESS ) {
    NSLog(@"Memory in use (in bytes): %u", info.resident_size);
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Error with task_info(): %s", mach_error_string(kerr));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please confirm you are running on hardware and not the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers cannot be compared really. Even pages belonging to a (shared) memory mapped file (e.g. a library) will count as resident pages for the task. But they will be ignored by the Leak Tester.

The important thing to note is that there is a conceptual difference between memory available to the process (in whatever way: readonly, read/write, executable or not) and memory allocated by you, within your program. Not all available memory is connected to an actual allocation you did (e.g. a shared library) and not all memory you allocate is necessarily resident in memory (e.g. a big malloc will not reserve physical memory for you right away, but only as soon as it is used).

You can test the impact of this by mapping an anonymous region of memory (or a file) using:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

// allocate anonymous region of memory (1 mb)
char *p = mmap(NULL,1024*1024,PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,0,0);

// actually access the memory, or it will not be resident
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<1024*1024;i++ ) sum += p[i];
```

You can easily change this to `mmap` a file, by passing an fd to `mmap` and changing `MAP_ANON` to `MAP_FILE`.

Also, presumably the leak tester looks from the `malloc` (library) call onward until a corresponding `free`, while the actual memory reservation is done just one level lower, e.g. using a `mmap` (system) call just like the one above.

Comment: In Instruments, I am seeing that the memory returned by task_info is much less than reported by the VM Tracker. Is this because task_info is only counting the memory from the process whereas VM Tracker is also including the shared memory?

Comment: No, most probably you are looking at the difference between resident memory (memory pages that are actually in RAM) vs. virtual memory (memory pages that reside on swap, on disk as files, or nowhere yet; see the mmap/MAP_ANON example). On Mac OS X, run `vmmap -resident $$` in your terminal to see the numbers for your shell (`$$` is the PID of your shell). As far as your process knows, the virtual pages are just there, but if you access them, the OS needs to get them first. Using `mincore(2)` you can test if a page of memory is resident, and if not, you can measure a delay when accessing it.

Comment: Taking an extreme example: you can `mmap()` an entire block device, like your 1TB harddisk, and your process can then simply access the disk contents from memory, instead of using `read()` system calls. The VM tracker will then say you have 1TB of virtual memory, with only a fraction of it resident in RAM. (note: you need a 64 bit OS for such experiments)

Comment: I get that, but what I'm wondering is why VM Tracker and task_info report different values for resident and virtual. Both tools give values for resident and virtual, but task_info reports a lower value for resident and higher value for virtual than VM Tracker, so I don't know what either is actually reporting.

Comment: dunno, maybe your measurement influences your observable. Are you measuring at the exact same instant?

Comment: Pretty close to it... I wrote a test program to allocate memory on command and then output task_info while I measure with VM Tracker. The measurements from task_info and VM Tracker have fairly consistent offsets, but it would be nice to know why exactly they are different.

Comment: You would need to delve deeper I think. You could try to find out what calls `vmmap` makes to generate its list, maybe loop over the memory using `mincore` to actually verify the resident amount of memory yourself. Interesting from an academical perspective mostly, I think.