# Xcode app memory usage discrepancies unexplained

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using the following code to retrieve the amount of memory used by the app I am running on my device:

```
-(void)appRam
{
    task_basic_info         info;
    kern_return_t           rval = 0;
    mach_port_t             task = mach_task_self();
    mach_msg_type_number_t  tcnt = TASK_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
    task_info_t             tptr = (task_info_t) &info;

    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(info));

    rval = task_info(task, TASK_BASIC_INFO, tptr, &tcnt);
    if (!(rval == KERN_SUCCESS)) return 0;

    return info.resident_size;
}
```

However, the returned memory amount is much greater than what Xcode shows in its debug navigator. For example, at some specific point, the method above returned 30MB while Xcode showed only 8.2MB (See attached screenshot), I am looking to find what causes this discrepancy and how to fix my method to return an accurate memory app use amount. Anyone?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone / iPad IOS App Instrument Memory Count vs. task\_info Memory Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271717/iphone-ipad-ios-app-instrument-memory-count-vs-task-info-memory-count)